# Set Text to all caps when typing

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Just want to ask how to set text to all caps when typing in `textbox`

I've tried this, but it's not working.

```
void txt_AllCaps(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
       string s = (sender as TextBox).Text.ToString().ToUpper();
       (sender as TextBox).Text = s;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want while typing, make it caps when user stops typing

Comment: @shadow - actually i want it in a dynamic way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the `e.KeyChar` in the `KeyPress` event handler to what you want. Try this:

```
private void txt_AllCaps(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
    e.KeyChar = e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper()[0];
    //Or this
    //if (e.KeyChar > 96 && e.KeyChar < 123) e.KeyChar = (char) (e.KeyChar - 32);
}
```

You should choose the solution of `Shree`, it's much more convenient :)

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
YourTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Comment: they say that your answer is more convenient, but i already used the suggestion of king, but thanks anyway

Comment: Its ok may be this ans help another person. :)